How can I perform a Google search for an exact match of a line of code containing a question mark?
A comment on an GitHub repository issue has a code block that contains on line 13:
get => _items.Value == null ? _items.Value = ImmutableDictionary<string, object>.Empty : _items.Value;

When I perform a Google search for that string using quotation marks, the search returns nothing.
The reason could be the question mark in the code. Is there any way to escape or ignore it?
